# Single Linked List, C++ segmentation fault, add to list, print

Tags: c++, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I want to implement single linked list in C++. I have a segmentation fault problem. I think it's the add function issue. Can anybody check and say how can I imporove this?

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
private:
    float t;
public:
    T *next;
    T()
    {
        this->t = 0.0;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    T(float t, T* next)
    {
        this->t = t;
        this->next = next;
    }
    T(const T& tx)
    {
        this->t = tx.t;
        this->next = tx.next;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << this->t << "\n";
    }
};

class MyList
{
private:
    T *head;
public:
    T* add_T(T *x)
    {
        T *new_head = new T(*head);
        new_head -> next = head;
        head = new_head;
        return head;
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(T *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
            curr->print();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyList ml;
    T a,b,c;

    ml.add_T(&a);
    ml.add_T(&b);
    ml.add_T(&c);
    ml.print();

    return 0;
}
```

**EDIT:**

Still not what I wanted, because I see the 0 from head node.

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
private:
    float t;
public:
    T *next;
    T()
    {
        this->t = 0.0;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    T(float t)
    {
        this->t = t;
    }
    T(float t, T* next)
    {
        this->t = t;
        this->next = next;
    }
    T(const T& tx)
    {
        this->t = tx.t;
        this->next = tx.next;
    }
    float getT()
    {
        return this->t;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << this->t << "\n";
    }
};

class MyList
{
private:
    T *head;
public:
    MyList()
    {
        head = new T();
    }

    T* add_T(T *x)
    {
        head = new T(x->getT(), head);
        return head;
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(T *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
            curr->print();
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyList ml;
    T a(1),b(2),c(3);

    ml.add_T(&a);
    ml.add_T(&b);
    ml.add_T(&c);
    ml.print();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `new T(*head)`. On the first call, `head` is not initialized. Your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of accessing an uninitialized variable.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik: Even when I add a constructor to MyList `MyList()
    {
        head = NULL;
    }
` its the same

Comment: That's a bug as well. In that case you try to dereference a null pointer.

Comment: @drescherjm: changed it to: `MyList() { head = new T(); } ` but I do not want an empty head at first

Comment: You will have to initialize `head` and change the code for add_T() to handle the first node.

Comment: Well, if you initialize `head = NULL`, then your program exhibits undefined behavior by way of `*head` dereferencing a null pointer.

Comment: You only need to use `this->` notation when differentiating between member variables and parameters.  If you name them differently, you don't need to use `this->` at all.  By not using `this->` you are typing less, which means less chance of typos.

Answer (score 2):

As the comment says, you unconditionally dereferencing `head`, which invokes undefined behaviour. Since you are adding nodes to the head, you could simply do something like:

```
T* add_T(T *x)
    {
        head = new T(x->getT(), head);
        return head;
    }
```

Also, prefer to use `nullptr`, instead of `NULL`.

Also, give all your data members default values. e.g. in your `MyList` constructor, do:

```
 MyList()
    {
        head = nullptr;
    }
```

Comment: OK, but how should I change the constructor in T then?

Comment: Oops, that was a typo. edited the answer to use `T(float t, T* next)`.

Comment: OK, still wrong. I changed it (see the edited code). I needed to add the `getT` method, also, I still the first 0 from head node.

Comment: That's because your default constructor is allocating a `T`. See the edited answer.

Comment: What if I would like to use copy constructor in add method?

Comment: Then use the copy constructor. But make sure to implement it yourself. The defaulted copy constructor will *not* be correct., when you are manually dealing with memory.

Comment: But I implemented the copy constructor by myself. Somehow, hoewever, it does not work as I expect it

Comment: You need to call `new` in your copy constructor. Anyway, that should be a separate question.