# Sinlge Linked List, C++, problem with delete all and search functions

Tags: c++, linked-list, segmentation-fault, singly-linked-list

I tried to implement a single linked list. However, I have a problem with search and delete functions. Im getting segmentation fault, and I dont know why. Can someone probably explain me, what am I doing wrong, and how to improve this code to work? Thank you

```
#include <iostream>

class T
{
private:
    float t;
public:
    T *next;
    T()
    {
        this->t = 0.0;
        this->next = NULL;
    }
    float getT()
    {
        return this->t;
    }
    T(float t, T* next)
    {
        this->t = t;
        this->next = next;
    }
    T(const T& tx)
    {
        this->t = tx.t;
        this->next = tx.next;
    }
    void print()
    {
        std::cout << this->t << "\n";
    }
};

class MyList
{
private:
    T *head;
public:
    T* add_T(T *x)
    {
        T *new_head = new T(*head);
        new_head -> next = head;
        head = new_head;
        return head;
    }
    void print()
    {
        for(T *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
            curr->print();
    }
    void delete_all()
    {
        T *x = head;
        while (x!= NULL)
        {
            head = head->next;
            delete x;
            x = head;
        }
        head = NULL;
    }
    T * search_val(T * k)
    {
        if (this->head == NULL)
            return NULL;

        if (this->head->getT() == k->getT())
            return this->head;

        return search_val(this->head->next);
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyList ml;
    T a,b,c;

    ml.add_T(&a);
    ml.add_T(&b);
    ml.add_T(&c);
    ml.print();

    T *y = new T(3.14, NULL);
    T *x = ml.search_val(y);

    ml.delete_all();
    delete x,y;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Which line triggers the segmentation fault?

Comment: I thought this code was fixed last week. [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700490/single-linked-list-c-segmentation-fault-add-to-list-print](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61700490/single-linked-list-c-segmentation-fault-add-to-list-print) I am not sure why the broken implementation of `T* add_T(T *x)` with the uninitialized head pointer is back.

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> class MyList
> {
> private:
>     T *head;
> public:
>     T* add_T(T *x)
>     {
>         T *new_head = new T(*head);
>         new_head -> next = head;
>         head = new_head;
>         return head;
>     }
> ```

Q1: what does `head` point to when `MyList` is constructed?
A1: we can't know (it's undefined).

Q2: How come `add_T()` does not use the `x` parameter?
A2: It doesn't actually add the element pointed at by `x`, instead it duplicates current `head`.

Fixing these two bugs will get you further along.

See also: [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you list head is not initialized (should probably 0).
And why does your `T* add_T(T *x)` create a new element? It should probably just insert the given element into the list, not create a new one. If your List class had a `T head;` you could just add elements by calling something like

```
T* next = t.head;
t.head = x;
x->next = next;
```

In that case, destroying the list would be empty as the list elements come from the heap.

Answer (score 0):

The way you are handling nodes in `main()` is just all wrong.  Code outside of the list should be focusing on *values*, not on *nodes*.

You are not initializing the list's `head` member, as `MyList` is missing a default constructor.

`add_T()` is completely ignoring its `x` argument.  It is instead making a copy of the `head` node, and then inserting that copy to the front of the list.

You are trying to `delete` the node returned by `search_val()` after `delete_all()` has already `delete`'d that node.

Try something more like this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>

class MyNode
{
public:
    float data;
    MyNode *next;

    MyNode(float data = 0.0f, MyNode* next = NULL)
        : data(data), next(next)
    {
    }

    void print() const
    {
        std::cout << data << std::endl;
    }
};

class MyList
{
private:
    MyNode *head;

public:
    MyList()
        : head(NULL)
    {
    }

    ~MyList()
    {
        delete_all();
    }

    MyNode* addToFront(float value)
    {
        head = new MyNode(value, head);
        return head;
    }

    /*
    MyNode* addToBack(float value)
    {
        MyNode **curr = &head;
        while (*curr != NULL)
            curr = &((*curr)->next);
        return (*curr = new MyNode(value));
    }
    */

    void print() const
    {
        for(MyNode *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
            curr->print();
    }

    void delete_all()
    {
        for(MyNode *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = head)
        {
            head = curr->next;
            delete curr;
        }
    }

    MyNode* search_val(float value)
    {
        for(MyNode *curr = head; curr != NULL; curr = curr->next)
        {
            if (curr->data == value)
                return curr;
        }
        return NULL;
    }
};

int main()
{
    MyList ml;

    ml.addToFront(3.14f);
    ml.addToFront(2.99f);
    ml.addToFront(1.25f);
    ml.print();

    if (ml.search_val(3.14f) != NULL)
        std::cout << "found" << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "not found" << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```